# Fair-Whipple-Hsiao Q calculation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

This Equation:

```
J = 0,0008695  * (Q ^ 1,75 / D ^ 4,75)
```

Gives J for Fair-Whipple-Hsiao.

How to calculate Q using Wolfram Mathematica ?

Comment: You may get a better answer from [Mathematica StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to solve for Q in terms of J and D.  First, I'd recommend using lowercase letters to start your variable names as Mathematica starts all of its functions with uppercase letters and D is the name of a standard function.  You could use the following:

```
 Solve[j == (8695/10000000) (q^(175/100)/d^(475/100)), q]
```

Note that I've rationalized all of the numbers to avoid potential round-off error. This results in

```
 {{q -> (2000 5^(3/7) (d^(19/4) j)^(4/7))/1739^(4/7)}}
```